# Maps Between Reflexive Graphs (Conceptual Mathematics Exercise)

Tags: category-theory

Here is the question for the book. (Article 3 Exercise 30):
[image]
I'm struggling to get an intuition for how to solve this exercise. I am able to create the following diagram:
[image]

But not really sure where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Right hand s, i, t should be s’, i’, and t’